# Getting iPhone mainBundle Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, resources, nsbundle

I dont know the exact code i need to retrieve all of the filenames of the resources in my iphone apps mainBundle. if i could have some kind of code like:

```
  NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] getAllResourceFilenames];
```

it would be helpful. thanks inadvanced for any help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should look at the SDK documentation for NSFileManager, but this will get you started:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *directoryAndFileNames = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the resources path of the main bundle

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

and then simply use the regular NSFileManager methods to get its contents.

Comment: does this return to me a list of filenames?

Comment: Nope, that will just give you the correct path, you will then need to use NSFileManager to get the list of files and/or subdirectories (see Seamus' answer below).