# Get contents of directory from main bundle

Tags: ios

I am including a directory full of files in my app. I looked through the NSBundle docs, but I can't seem find out how to get the URL to this directory. I'm trying to use the main bundle object.

I have a directory "defaultImages" under a directory "Resources" in xCode. I have confirmed that these are being copied to the device, how do I get the URL to them?

Specifically, the following does not work.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]:URLForResource:@"defaultImages" withExtension:@"" subdirectory:@"Resources"];
```

Comment: Have a look at the `NSBundle` docs.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already did (edited)

Comment: Share code of what you have tried so far...

Comment: And try look around for the similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238143/iphone-ios-copying-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-folder-causes-crash   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428715/getting-iphone-mainbundle-files

Comment: @yunas, I've added the code I am trying to use

Comment: How are you saving the data to the device? I think that might be the issue

Comment: Looks like NSBundle does not locate directories, only file assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently NSBundle will not locate a directory for you. My solution was to put the contents of the directory inside a bundle, via [How to make an iOS asset bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888208/how-to-make-an-ios-asset-bundle). I then added that bundle to my main application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaultImages" ofType:@"footype"];
```